# How to create hover menu when clicked upon or hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

So I am unsure if I should be calling this a hover menu or not, and I basically want to have some text to have a little window hover up when hovered on or clicked on to show some info.

I made an example in Photoshop to the best of my ability to make an example.

[image]

Another example is like

[image]

but in this case I want it to go up.

Much help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Google after "tooltip" and try some example you find. There are some for jQuery also.

Comment: Your photoshop example looks like a tooltip, google's is more like a popover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this tooltip this is same as you need

[Tooltip](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is something i got for you,

[Bootstrap popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers)

It is easy to use, you can `popover` according to your requirement

`$('#example').popover(options);`

In options give `html:true` and `content:your_html_content`

Comment: it not display any html content

Comment: @ Shakti Patel : edited my answer, you have to give `html:true`